# Matching TCP connections between TcpClient and TcpConnectionInformation[]

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a `TcpClient` with `Client.LocalEndPoint` and `Client.RemoteEndPoint`.  The connection is active (to a local TCP server).

I gather the list of TCP connections via:

```
IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
```

When I try to find the connection within `connections`, I'm having a difficult time matching because the value/contents of `Client.LocalEndPoint` and `Client.RemoteEndPoint` are of a different form than those in `TcpConnectionInformation`.

e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
// [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:55853
```

and

```
foreach (var conn in connections)
{
  Console.WriteLine(conn.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + " to " + conn.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + ": " + conn.State.ToString());
  // 127.0.0.1:55853 to 127.0.0.1:8000: Established
}
```

As a result, this returns null:

```
var state = connections.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.LocalEndPoint.Equals(client.Client.LocalEndPoint)
                && x.RemoteEndPoint.Equals(client.Client.RemoteEndPoint));
```

It appears that the `TcpClient` is reporting a hybrid IPv6+IPv4 address, whereas `TcpConnectionInformation` is reporting only the IPv4 address.

Is there an effective cross-platform way of comparing to identify the connection information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since Windows is now fully dual-stacked, all IP addresses are represented as Ipv4-Mapped-To-IPv6 addresses ([RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.5.5)). These are not IPv6 addresses and cannot be routed as IPv6, they are simply used to represent IPv4 addresses on an IPv6 machine.

Quite why `TcpConnectionInformation` does not also show addresses this way is unclear.

To convert them, there is a function to convert back to standard IPv4:

```cs
var local = (client.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndpoint)?.Address;
if (local?.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 ?? false)
    local = local.MapToIPv4();

var remote = (client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint)?.Address;
if (remote?.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 ?? false)
    remote = remote.MapToIPv4();
```

You can also convert the other way if you want.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface is there a using statement I need to access the IsIPV4MappedToIPv6 property or MapToIPv4 method?

Comment: These appear to be a property, method on IPAddress and not EndPoint or IPEndPoint.

Comment: Sorry see edits